# Integrating over polar coordinates and 6 dimensions

Tags: integration

I have a wave function as follows:
$$\psi=A \exp (\frac{r}{2a}-br^2-4bR^2) \tag{1}$$where $A$ is normalization constant. Normalization means 
$$A^2\int \psi^2d\tau=1 \tag{2}$$ so $A$ is $$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\int \psi^2d\tau}} \tag{3}$$
where $d\tau$ means whole space and in polar coordinates is $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\;\sin{\theta}\;d\theta\; r^2dr\tag{4}$$
when I try to obtain $A$ in (1) using (2-4) I get this
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{b \exp(-\frac{1}{8a^2b})}{1+Erf(\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{2b}})}}}{\pi^{3/2}} \tag{5}$$ where I have obtained $16\pi^2$ for integrating over  $d\theta_1,d\theta_2,d\phi_1,d\phi_2 $ because we have no arguments in (1) for them and then I have integrated over $r$ and $R$ using Mathematica. But the final result for $A$ in the paper which I try to reproduce its result is $$8(\frac{b}{\pi})^{3/2}\{(\frac{2}{x})\pi^{-1/2}+(1+\frac{2}{x^2})\exp(\frac{1}{x^2})[1+erf(x)]\}^{-1/2} \tag{6}$$ where $$x=2a {(2b)}^{1/2}$$ It's obvious that the general form of my $A$ is correct, but the coefficients don't match. I really don't know how to address this problem! Any idea?

**Addendum (For comment 1)**

For integrating over $r$ we get
$$\frac{\exp(\frac{1}{8a^2b}-8bR^2)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1+Erf[\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{2b}}])}{2\sqrt{b}} \tag{7}$$ and after integrating (7) over $R$ we obtain
$$\frac{\exp(\frac{1}{8a^2b})\pi^3(1+Erf[\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{2b}}])}{b} \tag{8}$$ and after inversion and get sqrt we reach to final result (5).

**Addendum 2**

When I evaluate the following expression in Mathematica
$$\int_0^{\infty} r^2 \exp (\frac{r}{a}-2br^2) \tag{9}$$ I get
$$\frac{4a\sqrt{b}+(1+4a^2 b)\exp (\frac{1}{8a^2 b})\sqrt{2\pi}(1+Erf[\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{2b}}])}{64a^2b^{\frac 5 2}} \tag{10}$$

Comment: Can you write out the $dr$ integral that you computed? This looks like there is just a small algebra error somewhere (maybe even in the paper and not in your math).

Comment: @quarague Done!

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and ˚\right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First they worked out
$$\begin{align}I_{\vec R}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dX\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dY\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dZe^{-8b(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)}\\
&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-8bX^2}dX\right)^3=\left(\frac1{\sqrt{8b}}\cdot2\cdot\frac12\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac12\right)\right)^3=\left(\frac{\pi}{8b}\right)^{3/2}\end{align}$$
Then they said
$$\begin{align}I_{\vec r}&=\int_0^{\infty}r^2\,dr\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi e^{\frac ra-2br^2}=4\pi\left(\frac1{2b}\right)^{3/2}\int_0^{\infty}r^2e^{\frac r{a\sqrt{2b}}-r^2}dr\tag{1}\\
&=4\pi\left(\frac1{2b}\right)^{3/2}e^{\frac1{8a^2b}}\int_0^{\infty}r^2e^{-\left(r-\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}\right)^2}dr\tag{2}\\
&=4\pi\left(\frac1{2b}\right)^{3/2}e^{\frac1{8a^2b}}\int_{-\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}}^{\infty}\left(r+\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}\right)^2e^{-r^2}dr\tag{3}\\
&=4\pi\left(\frac1{2b}\right)^{3/2}e^{\frac1{8a^2b}}\left\{\left[-\frac12\left(r+\frac1{a\sqrt{2b}}\right)e^{-r^2}\right]_{-\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}}^{\infty}\right.\tag{4}\\
&\quad\left.+\left(\frac12+\frac1{8a^2b}\right)\int_{-\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}dr\right\}\\
&=4\pi\left(\frac1{2b}\right)^{3/2}e^{\frac1{8a^2b}}\left\{\frac1{4a\sqrt{2b}}e^{-\frac1{8a^2b}}\right.\tag{5}\\
&\quad\left.+\left(\frac12+\frac1{8a^2b}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\operatorname{erf\left(\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}\right)}\right)\right\}\end{align}$$
In $(1)$ I said $\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\,d\theta=\left.-\cos\theta\right|_0^{\pi}=2$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi=\left.\phi\right|_0^{2\pi}=2\pi$. Then I let $r=\frac u{\sqrt{2b}}$.
In $(2)$ I completed the square: $-r^2+\frac r{a\sqrt{2b}}=-\left(r-\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}\right)^2+\frac1{8a^2b}$.
In $(3)$ I let $r=u+\frac1{2a\sqrt{2b}}$.
In $(4)$ I integrated $\int_{-1/x}^{\infty}re^{-r^2}dr=\left.-\frac12e^{-r^2}\right|_{-1/x}^{\infty}$ and integrated by parts $\int_{-1/x}^{\infty}r^2e^{-r^2}dr=\left.-\frac12re^{-r^2}\right|_{-1/x}^{\infty}+\frac12\int_{-1/x}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}dr$.
In $(5)$ I said $\int_{-1/x}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}dr=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\left(\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-r^2}dr+\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-1/x}^0e^{-2r^2}dr\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\left(1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac1x\right)\right)$.

With $x=2a\sqrt{2b},$ I get
$$\int\lvert\psi\rvert^2d\tau=I_{\vec R}I_{\vec r}=\frac{\pi^3}{64b^3}\left\{\frac2{x\sqrt{\pi}}+e^{1/x^2}\left(1+\frac2{x^2}\right)\left(1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\right\}$$
Is there a typo in your expression where you have $\operatorname{erf}(x)$? OK, so it's a typo in the paper. These kinds of things are hard to get right in a vast sea of typeset equations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No it's correct and it is interesting that I obtain your result when I evaluate your initial expression in Mathematica. So seems that the result presented in the paper is not correct. Can you explain how to integrate out $\theta$ ?How you obtain $(\frac{1}{2b})^{3/2}$?

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand your evaluation, can you explain it step by step? Also when I try to evaluate the integral for $r$ by Mathematica, I obtain a different result for coefficients where $x$ doesn't appear in denominator but in numerator! Anyway your result for error function is the same with Mathematica. What is the origin of these disagreements?

Comment: I can't see some of your steps, so I suspect the error lies in some step you took for granted. Like what happened to $r^2$? That's the factor that seems to result in most of the disagreement. Anyhow I laid out my logic line by line so hopefully what I am doing will be more comprehensible.

Comment: Many thanks. Please see the addendum 2. I  even tried equation 2 in our answer in Mathematica, but it returned the same result as 10. Though you have written your steps exactly, and they are correct, but I think that you will agree with me that Mathematica can't make mistake, right? I'm really confused

Comment: Looks to me like you input $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-r^2+\frac r{a\sqrt{2b}}}dr$$ into Mathematica rather than $$\int_0^{\infty}\color{red}{r^2}e^{-r^2+\frac r{a\sqrt{2b}}}dr$$ to get your expression $(7)$.

Comment: No as I said my input is (9) and the output becomes (10)!!

Comment: Yes I realize that and your $(10)$ is consistent with my answer, but the only way you could have gotten $(7)$ and $(8)$ was to omit the $r^2$ as I said in my previous comment and then to omit the $R^2$ in $$\int_0^{\infty}\color{red}{R^2}e^{-8bR^2}dR$$ Here, just look at it from the point of view of dimensional analysis: $e^x$ has no dimensions and after you integrate with the volume element over $2$ sets of coordinates your answer should have dimensions of $\text{length}^3$. Since $b$ has dimensions of $\text{length}^{-2}$ your answer has dimensions of $\text{length}^2$.

Comment: Yes you're right, you are really smart. But the main problem is coefficients disagreement where $x$ appears in denominator in your result. This is while $x$ appears in numerator for Mathematica result (10), I don't understand this!

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. If you multiply your $(10)$ by $4\pi$ for the angular integrals you get exactly my $(5)$.

Comment: OMG! Sorry! I had made a very awkward mistake! Thank you for your patience!